# Atomic increment for boolean variables(CUDA)

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a graph structure where I am maintaining whether I have visited a particular vertex or not(so that it is processed at most once). For that purpose I am using atomicInc function, which takes unsigned int variables, tests against a given value(1 for me) and increments if required.

However, the problem with atomicInc function is that, once it reaches the given value(1), it resets to 0, which I don't want since visiting a node two times would have the same value as never visiting it. What is the work around this? Is there a more appropriate function I can use or is there a smarter way to do this?

Note- I am doing this thing inside a kernel call in CUDA

Comment: Why not `std::atomic_bool`?

Comment: My bad for not making it more noticeable, I am doing this inside CUDA kernel function and cannot used the 'std' namespace.

Comment: You should have [`compare_exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) equivalent functions.

Comment: Oh yes! There is such a function, having never done these things, I could not think of anything apart from increment function. You may want to make this an answer, since it solves the problem.

Comment: It should be possible to [atomicOr](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicor) for this, also.

Comment: Yes, atomicOr would also work. I should have spent more time in the documents. Thank you.

Comment: You might answer yourself to your answer. I won't as I cannot test it on CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this can be done using `atomicExch()` function in CUDA.